# SQL Query - Row to columns not really a pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I'm trying to move certain fields of an ID into columns, but it doesn't appear to match all the pivot examples I am finding. All the examples I can find use some form of a grouping on a field value.  I want to use more of a placement regardless of the value in the field. I want to do this in a query without looping via code. 
Data source example (sorry couldn't figure out how to format a table on the post so I used a code snippet):

```
+----+--------+--------+
| ID | Field1 | Field2 |
+----+--------+--------+
|  1 | NULL   | NULL   |
|  2 | Jim    | 321    |
|  2 | Jack   | 54     |
|  2 | Sue    | 985    |
|  2 | Gary   | 654    |
|  3 | Herb   | 332    |
|  3 | Chevy  | 10     |
+----+--------+--------+
```

Result set I'm trying to generate:

```
+----+------+------+-------+------+------+------+
| ID | Col1 | Col2 | Col3  | Col4 | Col5 | Col6 |
+----+------+------+-------+------+------+------+
|  1 | NULL | NULL |       |      |      |      |
|  2 | Jim  | 321  | Jack  |   54 | Sue  |  985 |
|  3 | Herb | 332  | Chevy |   10 |      |      |
+----+------+------+-------+------+------+------+
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen if a row with (2,Kramer,13) suddenly shows up?

Comment: This is a pivot, you just need to pivot on multiple columns. What database are you using?

Comment: Additionally, to your first table sample, you have the ID showing repeated values.  Is there also an auto-increment column that is unique per row too?  If so, what is it

Comment: jarlh - I would expect Col7 & Col8 to show up with tall hair.

Comment: bluefeet - Sql Server, but there could be 50,000 different IDs. Then again, I don't have a good grasp on pivots.

Comment: DRapp - I do have a PK field I could use if helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a225a/1

```
;with cte as (
    select id
    , field1
    , field2
    , ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by id order by field1, field2) r 
    from @t   
)
select c1.id
, c1.field1 col1
, c1.field2 col2
, c2.field1 col3
, c2.field2 col4
, c3.field1 col5
, c3.field2 col6
from cte c1
left outer join cte c2 on c2.id = c1.id and c2.r = c1.r + 1
left outer join cte c3 on c3.id = c1.id and c3.r = c1.r + 2
where (c1.r % 3) = 1
```

**Explanation**

`ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by id order by field1, field2) r`.  This line ensures that we have a column counting up from 1 for each `id`.  This allows us to distinguish between the multiple rows.

The `CTE` is used to save typing the same statement for `c1`, `c2` and `c3`.

The joins ensure that all items in a row have the same id, and that data for col1, col3 and col5 (likewise for col2, col4 and col6) is taken from consecutive rows.  We're using `left outer` joins because there may not rows in the source table for these columns.

The `where` statement says to take the first row of each set of 3 for the data in `c1` (with `c2` and `c3` thus being the second and third of each set, thanks to the earlier join).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using dynamic sql that works though I'm sure there's a better way to do it. Caution, it's a bit painful. First it builds the list of columns to pivot and select, builds the dynamic sql and runs it.

```
DECLARE @PivotColumns as varchar(max), @SelectColumns as varchar(max), @sql as varchar(max)

SELECT @PivotColumns = ISNULL(@PivotColumns + ',', '') + ColNum,
       @SelectColumns = ISNULL(@SelectColumns + ',', '') + 'NULLIF(' + ColNum + ', ''NULL'') as ' + ColNum
from (select distinct 'Col' + cast(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by id order by id) as varchar) as ColNum 
     from (select id, 
                  isnull(field1,'NULL') as field1,
                  isnull(field2,'NULL') as field2 
            from weirdpivot) cols
unpivot
(
    value
    for col in (field1, field2)
) unpivoted) DistinctColumns

set @sql = '
select id, + ' + @SelectColumns + '
from (select 
        ''Col'' + cast(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by id order by id) as varchar) as colnum
        ,id
        ,value
        from (select id, 
                     isnull(field1,''NULL'') as field1,
                     isnull(field2,''NULL'') as field2 
              from weirdpivot) cols
unpivot
(
    value
    for col in (field1, field2)
) u) unpivoted
pivot
(
    max(value)
    for colnum in (' + @PivotColumns + ')
) p'

exec (@sql)
```